# urldate not being considered

Tags: bibtex

I am using IEEEtran as my bibliography style and using a Citavi bibtex file in my latex document. The problem is that **urldate** is not being taken by the compiler i.e. it is not shown in the pdf generated. I have also tried with **"note"** too, but it doesn't work. Please help.

```
@misc{DAVIESMEYERGmbH.,
abstract = {The Clean Energy Partnership (CEP) is europe's largest demonstration project in the area of hydrogen mobility.},
author = {{DAVIES MEYER GmbH} and Hamburg},
title = {Hydrogen production and storage},
url = {https://cleanenergypartnership.de/en/faq/hydrogen-production-and-storage/},
keywords = {Berliner Verkehrsbetriebe BVG;BMW Group;Bohlen {\&} Doyen;CEP;Clean Energy Partnership;Daimler;energy;Environment;Ford;GM/Opel;Hamburger Hochbahn;Hydrogen;Linde;nonpolluting;Shell;StatoilHydro;TOTAL;Vattenfall Europe;Volkswagen},
urldate = {2019-07-17}
```

}

The output generated is as shown below:
[image]

Comment: The `IEEEtran` bibliography style isn't programmed to recognize -- and hence doesn't do anything with -- a field called `urldate`. Have you tried changing `urldate = {2019-07-17}` to `note = {Last checked on 2019-07-17}` and performing a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more)?  Incidentally, you *really* need to verify that `author = {{DAVIES MEYER GmbH} and Hamburg}` is correct. I harbor some serious doubts in this regard; I'd give `author = {{Clean Energy Partnership}}` a try. (Note the doubled curly braces, which inform BibTeX that this is a "corporate" author.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys the problem is solved now. I just replaced the IEEEtran.bst file with a file called IEEEtranUrldate.bst which is custom made by someone to rectify this issue. The problem is that IEEEtran doesn't recognise urldate because it is not meant to by default. Thus this has been updated in IEEEtranUrldate.bst. Here is the link for somebody who needs this:
[Adding a urldate field to the standard IEEEtran.bst file](https://github.com/ionaic/bibtex-ieeetran-urldate)

Now it's showing as desired:
[image]

Thanks guys for your input and valuable suggestions.